# How can i hook into django migrations for django 1.8

Tags: python, django, migration

I am using django 1.8.

Now i need to add some custom fields based permisions so i have created a YML file from python models like this

```
description:
    permissions: ['ADMIN']
award:
    permissions: ['USER']
```

Its working fine but my issue if some chnages the field names or reomves some field then i also need to reflect that in my yml file as well.

SO i was thinking when user runs the migration then if some how i could be able to see

1. If field is removed then i need to delete that entry from yml file
2. If field is renmaed then i need to rename it
3. if new field is added then i need to add blank row for it

How can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When migration created, you can manually change the base migration class to your custom subclass with overridden `apply` method

```
from django.db import migrations

class MyBaseMigration(migrations.Migration):
    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        for operation in self.operations:
            """
            Examine operation classes here and provide end-user notes
            """
         return super(MyBaseMigration, self).apply(project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=collect_sql)
```

Comment: I did not get it how to use. i want something automatic. what you are saying is to manually chnage the migration file. If i have to do it manually then its better to chnage yml directly.

Comment: Is it possible to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-migrate

Comment: post migrate have no information about migration operations. In case of automatic notifications, why are you asking about a notification on migrations run? May be you need notifications when migration file created?

Comment: I think you are right. i need notification when migration file is created. is there any way to do that

Comment: In this case you can subclass `createmigration` command, and override `write_migration_files` method. Just put the custom management command into `yourapp/management/commands/createmigration.py` See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py